# Segmentation Fault Using LLDB

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, lldb

When I was debugging my .c file using lldb on terminal for Mac, I some how cannot find the location of the segmentation fault. I have debugged the code numerous of times and it is still producing the same error. Can someone help me on why I can find the location of segmentation fault. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVURU.png)

Comment: Can you copy your debugger output as code? That would make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `bt` command in lldb to see the call stack.  You've called a libc function like `scanf()` and are most likely passing an invalid argument to it.  When you see the call stack, you will see a stack frame with your own code on it, say it is frame #3.  You can select that frame with `f 3`, and you can look at variables with the `v` command to understand what arguments were passed to the libc function that led to a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your code is doing, I would suggest using a tool like [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) instead of just a normal debugger. It's designed to look for memory issues for lower-level languages like C/C++/FORTRAN. For example, it will tell you if you're trying to use an index that is too large for an array.

From the [quick start guide](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.intro), try `valgrind --leak-check=yes myprog arg1 arg2`